# Reconnecting to a NamedPipeServerStream after unexpected loss or crash

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I have two applications talking to each other via `NamedPipes`. Let's call them `appServer` (server) and `appClient` (client). They successfully connect and send data back and forth for some length of time. Then, unexpectedly, `appClient` crashes. The user relaunches it and tried to connect to the pipe but `appServer` still thinks that it is connected and so isn't listening for a new connection.

I am currently using a `NamedPipeServerStream`on the server side (which returns `.IsConnected` as `true`, and `NamedPipeClientStream` on the client side (which returns `.IsConnected` as `false`).

My question is this: can I somehow get the client side to be able to reconnect? I've obviously tried `.Connect` with or without a timeout but no luck.

Any tips are appreciated! 
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Another valid (albeit undesirable) option would be performing some cheap operation on the server side to basically do a 'connection test' to make sure the client is 'still there'. Anyone know one of these? Besides sending a dummy message I'm not sure the best way of doing this. I don't like this option as it would have to happen continuously but I'm open to all avenues right meow.

Comment: An IOException should be thrown in your server code if the pipe is broken or disconnected. Are you sure you're not getting that (perhaps suppressing it?) Are you sure that the client process terminates?

Comment: During testing I'm the one explicitly killing the process. I am not seeing any exceptions thrown; where would you expect it to be thrown? The server is basically just sitting there waiting. Is there something I can do to explicitly set off an exception that would be 'cheap'?

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, the server code should get an IOException if the pipe is broken https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx. If the client crashes (or you kill it for testing), I would expect the IOException to trigger. Can you post a small code example that illustrates the problem you are seeing?

Comment: My code sits in a `do-while` loop that is based on `IsConnected` being true. But since the server isn't receiving any requests, none of the code fires and thus no exceptions. If I could add a secondary condition to the loop that basically just tests for the client existence it would be ideal but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The example code at the link above fires up several threads on the server side. Each thread can accept connections. I do think though it would be better to understand why the server waits for a client that has terminated than to try and work around the behavior. If you can post actual code, I or someone else may be able to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution ended up being to initiate a second thread that waited for another connection. We then compared the client and if it was the same client then we closed and recycled the original server pipe to keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, NamedPipeServerStream does not detect a connection is closed until you try to send something with it.

The easiest workaround is to regularly send a single short message, like a specific byte, and program the client to ignore them.

Alternatively you could simply periodically close and re-open the connection on both sides, which uses some resources, but might be easier to implement depending on your logic.